# Finding angle between vectors if not coplanar

Tags: vectors

$\|A\| = \|C\|\ = 5, \|B\| = 1$.

The angle, $\theta$, between A and B = $\pi/8$. And a constraint is ||A -B + C|| = || A + B +C||. I want to find the $\phi$ between B and C.

So I said let U = A + C. Thus the equation becomes || U - B || = || U + B||.

So B is either 0 (which it can't be because we've assumed ||B|| = 1) or B is perpendicular to U.

After drawing some pictures, I arrived at the solution $\phi$ = $3\pi/4 + \pi/8 = 7\pi/8$, which is the correct answer. However, I've noticed that the pictures assume A,B,C are all coplanar. But if B is perpendicular to U, B need not be coplanar with U. So $\phi = \pi/2$ if B is orthogonal and not coplanar with U. Is this right? Because I've been told that $7\pi/8$ is correct.

Comment: What is the distinction between $\theta$ and $\phi$? You state the angle $\theta$ between $B$ and $C$ in $\pi/8$ and then ask for the angle $\phi$ between $B$ and $C$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $||A-B+C|| = ||A+B+C||$ implies $(A,B) = -(C,B)$. The angle $\theta$ between $A$ and $B$ satisfies $$\cos \theta = \frac{(A,B)}{||A||\,||B||}$$ so that $(A,B) = 5 \cos \dfrac \pi 8$. The angle $\phi$ between $B$ and $C$ satisfies $$ \cos \phi = \frac{(B,C)}{||B||\, ||C||} = - \frac{(A,B)}{||B||\, ||C||} = - \cos \frac \pi 8.$$ Since $0 \le \dfrac{7\pi}{8} \le \pi$ and $\cos \dfrac \pi 8= - \cos \dfrac{7\pi}8$ you get $$\phi = \cos^{-1} \left( - \cos \frac \pi 8 \right)=\cos^{-1} \left( \cos \frac{7\pi}{8} \right) = \frac{7\pi}{8}.$$

$A$, $B$, $C$ do not need to be coplanar.

Comment: why does (A,B) = -(C,B)?

Comment: $||A+C-B||^2 = ||A+C||^2 - 2(A+C,B) + ||B||^2$ and $||A+C+B||^2 = ||A+C||^2 + 2(A+C,B) + ||B||^2$. 

Since they are equal you get $(A+C,B) = 0$.

Comment: so how does that get you (A,B) = -(C,B)?